Displaying most recent unique form submissions
I have an example spreadsheet located here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1alpX4Mlj9x9Ho8s6iFyJle3wF1aA9QH8b_oZGC7zwAw/. All names have been generated to protect identities.
There is a form linked to the tab "Form Responses". The Google Form asks users for their name and availability for 3 different jobs, Job1, Job2, and Job3. Their submissions will be recorded in the "Form Responses" tab as such: https://i.imgur.com/9wpun7H.png
I have another tab called "Master List", and I'd like for it to sort the answers each person gave, but I don't want it to list duplicate names and I only want it to list the most recent answers if it encounters duplicates.
So, everyone submits, and let's say that a few days later, three people have changed their minds and re-submit the form with different responses. The answers for Maeghan Wembley, Talbot Parris, and Deirdre Toft I have highlighted in red are no longer valid, and I want to now only take the answers for their most recent submissions as shown: https://i.imgur.com/3d1pXmr.png
Therefore, the desired output in the Master List tab should look like the following, where only the data from 6-30-2024 displays for Maeghan Wembley, Talbot Parris, and Deirdre Toft : https://i.imgur.com/ZZ3bzeO.png
I have been trying to work with QUERY() commands, but I could not figure out how to incorporate a check for unique names so that it is only taking the most recent submission from a name. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I have also tried using SORTN() but I'm not understanding it enough to make it work.


You may try:
=sort(sortn(sort('Form Responses'!A2:E,1,),9^9,2,2,1))



Try the following formula-
=QUERY(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(TOCOL('Form Responses'!B2:B,1)),
LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,CHOOSEROWS(SORT(FILTER('Form Responses'!A2:E,'Form Responses'!B2:B=x),1,0),1)))),
"order by Col1 offset 1")



Another alternative is;
=UNIQUE(MAP('Form Responses'!B2:B, LAMBDA(Ø, XLOOKUP(Ø, 'Form Responses'!B2:B, 'Form Responses'!A2:E,,0,-1))))

.


Thanks for everyone's time and helpfulness!
I kept watching tutorials on SORTN() and I came up with the following solution that is producing the desired results:
=SORT(sortn(sort('Form Responses'!$A$2:$E,1,0),9^9,2,2,1),1,1 )

Edited to reflect Haluk's answer, thank you!

Your formula is close to what @rockinfreakshow has suggested, but yours' is not working. It should be =SORT(sortn(sort('Form Responses'!$A$2:$E,1,0),9^9,2,2,1),1,1 )

I'm not sure why, but when I try pasting the formulas presented in the other solutions, including this one you've just provided, it returns ALL of the entries in the Form Responses sheet. The only thing that is working for me and providing JUST the most recent unique entries is =SORT( { sortn(sort('Form Responses'!$A$2:$E,1,0),9^9,2,3,1) },1,1 )

Share your file with "edit" permissions and let me try...

In the test sheet, the NAME is 2nd column & everyone provided a possible solution based on that & from your above formula, it seems like your main sheet has the NAME in 3rd column!!

This is exactly right, my apologies. The example sheet left out some very personal information to conceal identities that would exist on the true spreadsheet, and I completely forgot to take that into account. Now that I go back and try all of these solutions, all of them are providing the desired output in the example spreadsheet. They were not working in the real spreadsheet due to the extra column and my oversight. Thank you, everyone!
